# How to configure group settings for docker admin?

Tags: command-line, docker, administration, groups, container

Listing docker containers:

```
docker ps -a -q
```

error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

temporary fix:

```
grep docker /etc/group
newgrp docker
```

Oddly, if I exit out of `bash` from the `Gnome Terminal` I have to re-run the group command(s) above.

Why?  And, how to make that configuration persist?

Comment: You need to start a new login session for new group changes to take effect. That's what you're doing in a limited way with `newgrp` anyway.

Comment: I logged out with the gui and logged back in so don't understand why I'm still seeing that error.

Comment: See the dupe, in newer versions if you logout your session itself left alive.

Comment: yes, I used `loginctl terminate-user` and thanks for the response.